# Python- 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10' When Converting a List with Strings to Integers

Tags: python, pandas, google-dfp

I am using Pandas read_excel function to create data_frames for each column in my workbook. The data is being used with the [Google DFP API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/start) to create [Line Items](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201708/LineItemService) within our ad server.

I am looping through and passing the data from my data_frames into a dict as values. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from googleads import dfp

workbook = 'dfp-migration-data.xlsx'
sheet = 'main'

df = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name=sheet)

campaign_id = df['order_id'].tolist()
campaign = df['order'].tolist()
target = df['placement_id']

placement_id = []

def create_line_item(client, orders):
     line_item_service = client.GetService('LineItemService')

line_items = []
for index, order in enumerate(orders):

    line_item = {
        'name': line_item_name[index],
        'orderId': int(campaign_id[index]),
        'targeting': {
            'inventoryTargeting': {
                'targetedPlacementIds': placement_id[index]},
             },

    line_items.append(line_item)

# Add line items to DFP
line_items = line_item_service.createLineItems(line_items)

# Display results
for line_item in line_items:
    print(f"Order ID: {line_item['orderId']}"
          f"Line Item: {line_item['name']}"
          f"Placement IDs: {line_item['targeting']['inventoryTargeting']['targetedPlacementIds']}\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfp_client = dfp.DfpClient.LoadFromStorage()
    create_line_item(dfp_client, campaign)
```

The problem I am having is with the `target` data frame which has multiple values in each cell. e.g.

```
df['placement_id'].head()
0    28816768, 28809669, 28809672, 28809675, 288092...
1    28825664, 28825670, 28825511, 28825673, 288256...
2    28825538, 28816006, 28814215, 28825544, 288254...
Name: placement_id, dtype: object
```

When passing `placement_id` into the `targetedPlacementIds` key, I receive an error, which makes sense as the data from my data frame is a string. However, if I try to wrap 'placement_id' with an `int()` function I receive a  *'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'* error. I have tried using to_numbers() and astype(int()) functions in Pandas but receive the same error.

How can I convert the placement_ids from strings to integers so I am able to pass the data into my `line_item` dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow each row to have a list of `int` values, below should work.

```
df['placement_id'] = df['placement_id'].apply(lambda x: x.split(", "))
df['placement_id'] = df['placement_id'].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])
```

And you will get this:

```
In [3]: df['placement_id'].head()
Out[3]:
0    [28816768, 28809669, 28809672, 28809675, 288092]
1    [28825664, 28825670, 28825511, 28825673, 288256]
2    [28825538, 28816006, 28814215, 28825544, 288254]
Name: placement_id, dtype: object

In [4]: type(df['placement_id'][0][0])
Out[4]: int
```